# Having Issues Trying To Implement Mock On Interfaces in Nunit

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, nunit, moq

I have been spending quite some time trying to figure out this problem, but so far no luck. I am trying to implement Mock Test on the following

I have service with two interfaces. One is to receive email/tweet messages  and other is to response back to them. These interfaces log information which needs to be asserted. However my problem so far is how to mock the two interfaces properly. Following are the details.

```
   [ServiceContract]
   Name=emailsystem
   callabackcont=typeof(Iemailcallback)
   Public Interface IemailReceived
   [OperationContract]
   Void EmailReceived(EmailResponse message, int messgID)



    //Than in my DataContract I have 
    [DataContract(Name=EmailRequest...]

     public EmailReceived(Email message, int mssgID)
     {

     }




    //for my response interfact Iemailcallback I have 
    [ServiceContract(Name= "xyz")]

    [OperationContract] (IsOneWay=true   )
    void EmailResponse(emailResponse)

     //for the above interface I have data contract 
     [DataContract]
     EmailResponse 
     this(status, mssg)
```

I am trying to Mock Test the EmailResponse and EmailRequest using Moq in NUnit. I have tried different ways but nothing works. I created Mocks

```
   var mockEmailRequest = new Mock<IEMailRequest>
   var mockEmailResponse = new Mock<Iemailcallback>

since I dont have return type on the methods so I guess it goes something like in setup


    mockEmailResponse.setup(x+>x.EmailResponse).Callback(.....);
```

Not sure how to implement. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the interface, but you won't be able to test the output/functionality if the return type is void.

If you are modifying an object that is being sent in, you might check that. Otherwise it's a black box.

Maybe what you should do instead is implement the interface in your test suite and for the method body of EmailResponse and EmailReceived, just print the parameters to the console.

For example:

```
public class EmailTestImplemtation : IEmailReceived {
   void EmailReceived(EmailResponse message, int messgID) {
      Console.out.WriteLine("Message: " + message.toString() + " MessageID: " + messgID);
   }
}
```

This is pretty useless though because all it proves is that your parameters are being passed correctly in other parts of the code.

When you get to dependencies, you can mock an interface, but you can't really unit test dependencies. In other words, you don't run unit tests against a live database. You mock the interfaces used on top of the database, but the actual functions that run the stored procedures/queries ... you leave those for integration tests, not unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Verify` function on the mock.  There are a couple ways to do this.

```
//when you know the parameter values to expect
mockEmailRequest.Verify(r=>r.EmailReceived(expectedEmail, expectedId));

//when you just want to verify some detail about the values
mockEmailRequest.Verify(r=>r.EmailReceived(It.Is<EmailResponse>(r=>r.Subject == "Something"), It.Is<int>(i=>i > 17)));

//when you don't care about the values
mockEmailRequest.Verify(r=>r.EmailReceived(It.IsAny<EmailResponse>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
```

Read more about this at the [Moq Quick Start page](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart).

Comment: In one of these ways what if I wanted to run it 5 times with Thread.sleep(5000) like every five seconds. Is there a better way than to put a loop. Thanks

Comment: That seems like both a different question and a bad idea.  If you want to accept this answer (or not) for it's usefulness in answering this question and ask another question about that problem (perhaps with some details on why you want to do that and what you really want to accomplish by doing it), I'll be happy to help.